# Check if write_xlsx has correctly executed and the file has been written

Tags: r

I am using a code like this:

```
writexl::write_xlsx(
  x =  list(
"Sheet" = df
  ),
  path = paste0("User/", name,"_", date, ".xlsx")
  )
```

The code should write in the folder User that is in the wd the file.xlsx

I need that if the command not success in the writing operation the console display a message.

For example if in the object name there is a "/" windows not allow to write the file but any message appear to me. Also if for permission problem windows not allow to write the file.

I just tried with TryCatch without success.

Thanks

Comment: What did your attempt with `tryCatch` look like exactly? How did it not work?

Comment: I tried in this way:

test <- tryCatch(writexl::write_xlsx(
  x =  list(
    "Sheet" = data
  ),
  path = paste0("User/", name,"_", date, ".xlsx")
),
     error=function(e) {NA})

But in "test" I get [1] "C:\\Users\\......xlsx" also if I force and put a "/" in the filename and file was not written